# ZPL code to replicate a scanned barcode

Tags: javascript, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm using a bluetooth barcode scanner and a wireless zebra printer to replicate barcodes that the scanner scans.  When I scan barcodes that include letters and numbers it messes with the human readable portion of the replicated bar code as you can see it is trying to print the last character over the top of the 4th character, otherwise it works fine on pure number barcodes.  What am I missing?

The process is simple, use the wireless barcode scanner to scan the original barcode.  It sends the data to the wireless printer and the printer automatically reprints the barcode onto another label.

This is the code used to configure the print format:

```
^XA^DFE:BCI.zpl ^PW406 ^LS0 ^FT399,91^A0I,23,24^FH\^FDSerial No:^FS ^BY2,3,68^FT350,122^B3I,N,,N,N^FN1^FS ^FT260,87^A0I,37,36^FB137,1,0,C^FN1^FS ^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

This is the code to configure the barcode reader:

```
X 1 X 2rules_onDecode=function(a)    {comm.sendPacket("z","^XA^XFE:BCI.zpl^FS^FN1^FD"+a.data+"^XZ");return false}; X 3 X 5.rules.BCI.js&#0; X Z
```

[Original Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBopm.jpg) [Duplicated Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jnCn.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide an example where the replicated bar code is human readable so it easier to figure out the difference? Afaik ZPL always contains stuff like `^XA^LH 80,80`

Comment: The code provided does not seem to contain much of a barcode... Can you provide an example of both working and non-working codes, the expected result (for both) and the actual result (for both)?

Comment: Also, you're not giving us any details about the process to scan the data and generate the ZPL. Is that your own code? Can you provide the relevant parts of it?

Comment: I've updated the post with pictures of the original barcode and the reprinted barcode look like as well as added the other code I use to configure the barcode reader.

Comment: Can you provide the value of a.data from your debugger?